# return code in functions and overall return code

Tags: function, sh

Having a script that involves writing functions  that list return code in each of them.

- 0 if success
- 1 if critical error
- 127 if warning based on criticality

example:
script:

```
critical function 1{
 typeset retval=0
success: return 0
failure: return 1
return $retval
}

lessimp check function 2{

typeset retval=0
success: return 0
failure: return 127 (since its not a critical function and just a warning for me)
return $retval
}
```

how do i give an overall return code for the script having multiple functions like this. I want to give return code for entire script as 0 if everything is a success.  exit 1 if even something critical function failed and 127 if its just warning.

How would i do that?

Comment: What language are you writing in? It looks vaguely like, but isn't, POSIX shell.

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain two global variables (perhaps `haswarnings`, `haserrors`).

Every time a function returns you update the appropriate value.

At the end of the script, check the values and return appropriately:

```
#!/bin/sh

haserrors=0
haswarnings=0

update_global_return(){
    # must call immediately after function of interest
    # otherwise "$?" will no longer have correct value
    returncode="$?"
    case "$returncode" in
        127) haswarnings=1 ;;
        1)   haserrors=1 ;;
    esac
    # reset "$?"
    return "$returncode"
}

do_global_return(){
    # could use exit instead of return here
    case "$haserrors,$haswarnings" in
        1,*) return 1 ;;
        0,1) return 127 ;;
        *)   return 0 ;;
    esac
}

# ...

critical_function_1
update_global_return

# ...

lessimp_check_function_2
update_global_return

# ...

do_global_return
```